# How to get the second to the highest monthly sales for every year

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the second to the highest monthly sales for every year.

So far I'm getting the second highest monthly sales for the first year only.

```
WITH newtable AS
(
    SELECT 
    MONTH(o.orderdate) AS 'MONTH',
    YEAR(o.orderdate) AS 'YEAR',
    SUM(od.qty*od.unitprice) AS monthSales
    FROM Sales.Orders AS o
    INNER JOIN Sales.OrderDetails AS od
    ON o.orderid = od.orderid
    GROUP BY YEAR(o.orderdate), MONTH(o.orderdate) 
)
SELECT YEAR, MAX(monthSales) AS secondHighestMonthlySales
FROM newtable
WHERE monthSales < (SELECT MAX(monthSales) FROM newtable)
GROUP BY YEAR;
```

I need the second highest for every year.

Comment: The simplest alteration would be something like: `WHERE monthSales < (SELECT MAX(monthSales) FROM newtable AS n WHERE n.YEAR = newtable.YEAR)`. Alternatively, you could avoid needing to use the CTE twice by adding a row_number window function in the CTE logic to order the monthsales (e.g. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(o.orderdate) ORDER BY SUM(od.qty*od.unitprice) DESC) as RN`), then select only those where it = 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the data correct in newtable, focus on the second query regarding what you want. This is pure SQL:

Test Data:

```
Year    Sales
2010    500
2010    400
2010    600
2011    700
2011    800
2011    900
2012    400
2012    600
2012    500
```

Query to select the second highest:

```
select O.year, max(O.sales) as secondhighestsale from Orders O,
(select year, max(sales) as maxsale
from Orders
group by year) A
where O. year = A.year
and O.sales < A.maxsale
group by O.year
```

Output:

```
year    secondhighestsale
2010    500
2011    800
2012    500
```

Comment: First, thank you @Chiranjib, another question how do you call it an (outer subquery)?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking here. :/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use the ROWNUMBER() function. In this case, I use a common table expression. We find the second highest number of total sales for each year. These years are the so-called partitions.

```
USE TEMPDB

CREATE TABLE #Sales (SalesYear INT, TotalAmount INT)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES (2016, 1100), (2016, 700), (2016, 950),
                          (2017, 660), (2017, 760), (2017, 460),
                          (2017, 141), (2018, 999), (2018, 499);

WITH CTE AS 

(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesYear ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC) AS RowNumb 
    FROM #Sales
)

SELECT SalesYear,
      TotalAmount
FROM CTE WHERE RowNumb = 2
```